# Automatically a cell of a week

Tags: excel

I am creating a [spread sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V2yQ.jpg) that should automatically highlight cell in as color green.

As you can see in the attached, the cell to be automatically shaded green should represent the week in that month when a child should turn 1 year.

I don't know if its just formula in Excel or writing some macro to do this whenever a new entry is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with conditional formatting.  Highlight the range under the header row and right of the the dates.

Assuming your data starts with the first date in A2, and first week number in C1...Then go to Conditional Formatting, and add this under a custom rule `=weeknum($A2)=C$1`.  Then choose green for the fill, and apply!

Or change it to `=weeknum($B2)=C$1` if you want to base the weeks off the 1 year mark.

Comment: I am so grateful Sir. This has perfectly worked for me and I really appreciate.